# Some process always use CPU 100%

Tags: linux

As in the screenshot below, there is a process use CPU for more than 1300%. If I kill the process, then another process will be create about half an hour later, and the process name will change.

[image: top]

Comment: This looks like a trojan bitcoin miner. I suggest you change your root password and look for ways that your machine got access. You can look in `/proc/{pid}` to see other aspects of the process, like where its stored.

Comment: thank you very much, I did that as you say, and i got this
"/proc/4061/exe -> /usr/bin/09e63552aad41e5106cf1568273b2b93 (deleted)",I cd /usr/bin , but can`t find '09e63552aad41e5106cf1568273b2b93'

Comment: do you know how to removal it ?

Comment: Even more likely because of that. Removing the mechanism of reinfection. This is a lot more intensive than a superuser discussion can help with. Suggest getting professional help or finding a suitable irc/slack/real time discussion with a helper. In the mean time `kill -STOP {processid}; renice -n 19 {processid}` to minimse its impact on your host..

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a malware bitcoin miner. I suggest you change your root password and look for ways that your machine got accessed (at a root level).

In the mean time `kill -STOP {processid}`; `renice -n 19 {processid}` to minimse its impact on your host.

There are a large number of mechanisms that can keep a access there. Consider safely backing up your data (and not code) and moving this to a new freshly installed host. Reinstall code from a safe source.

Identifying how access got there is a key part of making sure it doesn't happen again. Given it was root access I'd be looking at your ssh logs and disable password based authentication, especially on the root account.

Comment: thank you very much, it sames there isn`t another way to fix it.now i am prepare to reinstall it, thanks again.

Comment: @贺明光 here's a generic link about compromised servers on SF: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)